# How to get a JSON table back from an openCPU RPC request?

Tags: r, opencpu

I've written an R function in my package which returns a data frame. I'd like to call my function from javascript and use it to populate a table. I am able to successfully call the function using the `ocpu/test` interface and get back `JSON`.

I'm looking for a minimal example of how to do it with `ocpu.rpc`. I was thinking it could be finding the leading rows of the `faithful` data set using `head`: e.g. `head(faithful)`. However, I think that the `ocpu.rpc` request can't be used with data already in R.

Based on the documentation, I thought the code should be:

```
ocpu.seturl("http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/mylib/R");
var req = ocpu.rpc("func", { x : "param" }, function(obj) { return obj });
```

But `req` is undefined when I inspect it. What am I missing?

Comment: The JSON object is `obj` in the body of the function, I think.